# How to reset the restart-policy for a Docker stack container

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, restart

I'm deploying a container using docker stack with a restart-policy. One of the container's attached volumes had some corrupted data, causing the container to repeatedly crash and eventually hit the max_restarts limit. I manually fixed the volume, and now want to restart the container. I have been unable to find a graceful way to ask Docker "please reset the max_restarts on this container". Does one exist?

I was able to proceed by doing a `service rm` and then re-create the service, but this seems a bit heavy-handed just for resetting a flag